# How to access an object instantiated as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, arguments, composition

Assume that `class Cheddar` inherits from a class which expects an object as a parameter; essentially composition:

```
class Brand {
    constructor(b) {
        this.brand = b;
    }
    getBrand() { 
        return this.brand;
    }
}

class Cheese {
    constructor(brand_obj) {
      // do stuff...
    }
}
```

**1**

```
class Cheddar extends Cheese {
    constructor(b) {
        super(new Brand(b)); // <-- HERE, I'm a "one-liner" kinda guy :D
    }
}
```

Now when I instantiate:

```
let snack = new Cheddar("Cabot Clothbound");
```

I can't access the Brand object, because it was created as an argument.

So, I tried to create the Brand and put it on the object before calling super, like this:

**2**

```
class Cheddar extends Cheese {
    constructor(b) {
        this.brand = new Brand(b);
        super(this.brand);
    }
}
```

...which results in the following error:

```
'this' is not allowed before super()
```

Grr.. so, I could do it this way:

**3**

```
class Cheddar extends Cheese {
    constructor(b) {
        let myBrand = new Brand(b);
        super(myBrand);
        this.brand = myBrand;
    }
    getBrand() {
        return this.brand.getBrand();
    }
}
```

And I can now happily access the methods on the cheese object like so:

```
let snack = new Cheese("Cabot Clothbound");
console.log(snack.getBrand()); //-> Cabot Clothbound
```

...but, it's getting messy. I want to be a "one-liner guy."

Anyway to access the object created as an argument to this constructor, or can I possibly structure things a bit differently to make this easier? I feel like I'm working too hard here. Thx, Keith :^D

Comment: Why not just `this.brand = myBrand;`? It's unclear why you want the `delete` and `jQuery.extend` in there.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: look at the error: ``'this' is not allowed before super()``

Comment: It needs to be after `super` like in your third example, you just suddenly also added a bunch of other code in (3) and I can't tell why.

Comment: True let me fix. I thought that I needed to make a deep copy.

Comment: Why have `getBrand` at all?

Answer (score 1):

You are not finishing the construction of `Cheese`. Your `// do stuff` should include saving the `brand_obj` if you want to access it from subclasses.

When you call `super(new Brand(b))` the brand object will end up in the super class's constructor. But you aren't doing anything with it there. If save the brand as a property on the super class it will be available to the subclass:

```js
class Brand {
  constructor(b) {
    this.brand = b;
  }
  getBrand() {
    return this.brand;
  }
}

class Cheese {
  constructor(brand_obj) {
    this.brand = brand_obj // <= save this!!
  }
}

class Cheddar extends Cheese {
  constructor(b) {
    super(new Brand(b));
    console.log("brand in cheddar constructor", this.brand) //<== now you can use it
  }
}

let snack = new Cheddar("Cabot Clothbound");
console.log("Brand on instance: ", snack.brand)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you... good suggestion; but in my case, I do not have permission to modify the ``super`` class. It's a packaged library, and I can only extend. :/

Comment: @kmiklas So when you use the superclass by itself and you pass it the parameter like `let c = new Cheese(brand_Obj)` is the brand object available in any way from the instance it created?  Like `c.brand_obj` What does `Cheese` do with that parameter ?

Comment: I checked the constructor of the ``super`` class. It uses the parameter for some stuff, but doesn't attach it as a key on the parent object, or on the prototype chain. I might be able to sneak it in... if I'm nice about it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer @kmiklas. In that case you might be stuck with `Grr.. so` case 3.